# Set DIV-Container between list-elements via CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible as to set a div-container after the 3th li in dynamic ul? 
[image]

Now, I have a ul-container with x li-elements.

My Plan:

```
<ul>
<li>xxx</li>
<li>xxx</li>
<li>xxx</li>
<li>xxx</li>
<li>xxx</li>
<li>xxx</li>
</ul>
<div> It would be cool if I'm after the 3th li-element only per CSS! </div>
```

Possible solution: li:nth-child(3) and then set the div absolute?

Thank you!!

ADD: My li-elements has min-height: 50px and max-height 100px (responsive)

Comment: No worries...I was just wondering why you put the other tags on the question.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible in the manner you describe as only `li` can be direct children of `ul` elements.

Instead you could append the `div` to be a child of the third `li` element, like this:

```
$('div').appendTo('ul li:eq(2)');
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: hi @RoryMcCrossan please you could help me to create a tag ingram-micro, i'm not able yet, and i have a question for that integration, or how I could ?.